# disable picture blending on picture box (Windows forms c#)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, picturebox

Im trying to make it so I can display a low res image in a picture box without picture blending / anti aliasing.

I have tried this code but it doesn't seam to work because it still looks blurred:

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        }

        private void pb_Image_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        }
```

Comment: You also need to draw the image :)

Comment: @Jimi [...]_Paint is an event that invokes on paint and not an override void or something. Therefore I dont have to draw anything myself because Windows.Forms does that by itself.

Comment: Your code only affects what you draw after that.  Do you have the PictureBox set to stretch maybe?

Comment: @LarsTech I have it set on Zoom. And how do I make it so my code runs before it is drawn?

Comment: Setting the device context's properties in `Form1_Paint` **event** has no effect on pbox image nor on the Form's painting itself. It's already done at that point. Now the pbox, if you just want to set the DC's properties and let the base completes the rest, then you need to derive a new class from `PictureBox`, override the `OnPaint` method, set the properties in question, **and** finally call the base method `base.OnPaint(e);`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment from @dr.null I have come to a solution (:

```
class PixelBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        pe.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

[image]